# Vue & Vuex splice -- cannot read property of null. Without splice content renders fine

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When using Vuex and computed property it returns this error.
Im out of ideas as I tried for several hours to fix it.
it seems the data is not available when it tries rendering the template. The strange thing is, when I don't use splice the error doesn't show up.

error

```
Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null"
```

template

```
        v-for="expert in experts"
            :key="expert.name"
            @click="goToProfile(expert.id)">
            <div class="experts__img">
                <LazyImage
                    :src="avatar(expert.file)"
                    :srcset="srcset(expert.file)"
                    :alt="expert.name"
                    :width="375"
                    :height="500"
                    :cover="true"/>
            </div>
```

script

```
    computed: {
    experts () {
        return this.$store.getters.experts.slice(0,3);
    },
```

If I alternatively use the splice in the frontend section I get the same error

```
        v-for="expert in experts.splice(0,3)"
            :key="expert.name"
            @click="goToProfile(expert.id)">
```

Comment: You seem to be using the words `slice` and `splice` interchangeably but from the code I assume you mean `slice`. Your theory sounds correct, the value of `experts` is `null` when you first try to render the template because it hasn't loaded yet. `v-for` can handle that. Presumably the value of `experts` then changes and the component is re-rendered with that new value. In the case where you try to use `slice` it will fall over during the first rendering. If `experts` is populated by something asynchronous then you'll just have to handle the case where the data hasn't shown up yet.

Comment: Yea I meant slice. but still the content doesn't rerender. Its an VUE SPA with Vuex and somehow once I use the slice the site doesn't render that component anymore and throws the error.
Also I use map getters to get the data in the first place which I put in the mounted() section. How to deal with asynchronous data that shall be used with computed properties ?

Comment: Once the error occurs you're stuck. You just need to handle the `null` in the first place to stop the error occurring. Without knowing exactly why you have a `null` it's difficult to speculate but you could put in a `null` check inside the computed property, or have the store getter return an empty array instead.

Comment: I used try and catch to prepare for the error which stops the error but then there comes no content after all.!?! it doesn't re-render then

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that in this code:

```js
computed: {
  experts () {
    return this.$store.getters.experts.slice(0,3);
  },
},
```

The `experts` Vuex getter is null. You need to ensure that the getter returns a non-null value at the time when the component is being rendered. Perhaps you didn't initialize some data properly initially? Alternatively you can write defensive code which handles the case when `experts` is null so you don't trigger the error.

You didn't provide your code for the `experts` Vuex getter, so I can't give you any further help.

Comment: I'd bet that OP has something like `store: { experts: null }` where they should have `experts: []`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so figured that I had experts: null in my state, but when I change it to experts:[] the error disappears but then still the content doesn't render at all now.

why doesn't the content show up once loaded? I thought computed with async would render once loaded!??!

Comment: I just found a working fix, but its the complete opposite.
I have to set expert:null in the state and use V-if="experts" in the parent div.
If I use experts:[] the error is gone but content won't render!